# Ruby: How to get the first character of a string

Tags: ruby, string

How can I get the first character in a string using Ruby?

Ultimately what I'm doing is taking someone's last name and just creating an initial out of it.

So if the string was "Smith" I just want "S".

Comment: As a side note, if you are in Rails you can just do `'Smith'.first`

Comment: Ruby 1.9+ has `"Smith".chr #=> "S"`

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can use Ruby's open classes to make your code much more readable.  For instance, this:

```
class String
  def initial
    self[0,1]
  end
end
```

will allow you to use the `initial` method on any string.  So if you have the following variables:

```
last_name = "Smith"
first_name = "John"
```

Then you can get the initials very cleanly and readably:

```
puts first_name.initial   # prints J
puts last_name.initial    # prints S
```

The other method mentioned here doesn't work on Ruby 1.8 (not that you should be using 1.8 anymore anyway!--but when this answer was posted it was still quite common):

```
puts 'Smith'[0]           # prints 83
```

Of course, if you're not doing it on a regular basis, then defining the method might be overkill, and you could just do it directly:

```
puts last_name[0,1]
```

Answer (score 114):

If you use a recent version of Ruby (1.9.0 or later), the following should work:

```
'Smith'[0] # => 'S'
```

If you use either 1.9.0+ or 1.8.7, the following should work:

```
'Smith'.chars.first # => 'S'
```

If you use a version older than 1.8.7, this should work:

```
'Smith'.split(//).first # => 'S'
```

Note that `'Smith'[0,1]` does *not* work on 1.8, it will *not* give you the first character, it will only give you the first *byte*.

Comment: note that this only works in ruby19.  in ruby18 `"Smith"[0]` would return the integer value of the character 'S'.  Both versions obey `"Smith"[0,1] == "S"`.

Comment: @rampion: Sure, but there's no indication in the question that the OP doesn't use the most recent version, so why bother complicating things?

Comment: I agree with Jörg. No need to answer questions for legacy software unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Ruby 1.8 is not legacy! The Ruby 1.8 line is still supported and there will most likely be a 1.8.8 version released. Moreover, neither JRuby nor Rubinius yet support 1.9.
I would bet 5$ that there are today far more users of 1.8 than 1.9.

Comment: @Marc-Andre Lafortune: given that every single solution given for Ruby 1.8 on this page, including the accepted one and the highest voted one *do not actually work*, it seems likely that neither the person who asked the question nor the people who answered it, are actually running 1.8 or they would have caught it during testing. I agree that most *users* are running 1.8, but this is not a user, this is a *learner* who literally just downloaded Ruby  an hour ago. He doesn't have a legacy application, he doesn't depend on third-party libraries. There would be no reason for him not to use 1.9.1.

Comment: `'Smith'[0,1]` gave "S" on Ruby 1.8.6 on my machine just now, and that's the answer I'd have given for that version. `'Smith'[0]` gives 83, which is what I'd expect per Pickaxe 2...

Comment: @Jörg: The answer `"Smith"[0,1]` does work on 1.8 (assuming ASCII). Not sure why you assume so much about the requester, as well as about everybody else who would like to learn from that question. For example, Mac OS X comes bundled with Ruby 1.8, so no installation is required for these users.

Comment: How would you get the initial of the name 'Ångström' (in UTF-8) so that it would work as expected in both Ruby 1.8.x and 1.9.x? Neither of the suggested methods would work in 1.8.x.

Comment: http://www.coderbyte.com/CodingArea/GuestEditor.php?ct=First%20Reverse&lan=Ruby    <-- gotta do str[0,1] to get the letter at position 0.  (otherwise you get the ascii number of the char at position 0). So that's using an early ruby version

Answer (score 33):

```
"Smith"[0..0]
```

works in both ruby 1.8 and ruby 1.9.

Comment: That's the best solution if 1.8.6 and 1.9 support is required.

Answer (score 28):

For completeness sake, since Ruby 1.9 String#chr returns the first character of a string. Its still available in 2.0 and 2.1.

```
"Smith".chr    #=> "S"
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chr

Comment: this is exactly the kind of sneakiness i was looking for. and unlike `.first`, it does not require rails to work with a string.

Answer (score 14):

In MRI 1.8.7 or greater:

```
'foobarbaz'.each_char.first
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
>> a = "Smith"
>> a[0]
=> "S"
```

**OR**

```
>> "Smith".chr
#=> "S"
```

Answer (score 12):

In Rails

```
name = 'Smith'
name.first
```

Comment: easy way to use. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
>> s = 'Smith'                                                          
=> "Smith"                                                              
>> s[0]                                                                 
=> "S"
```

Comment: note that this only works in ruby19.  in ruby18 `"Smith"[0]` would return the integer value of the character 'S'.  Both versions obey `"Smith"[0,1] == "S"`.

Comment: @rampion: indeed. I'd add that `"Smith"[0] == ?S` is true on both Ruby 1.8 and 1.9

Answer (score 5):

Another option that hasn't been mentioned yet:

```
> "Smith".slice(0)
#=> "S"
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of an annoying design choice in Ruby before 1.9 — `some_string[0]` returns the **character code** of the first character — the most portable way to write this is `some_string[0,1]`, which tells it to get a substring at index 0 that's 1 character long.

Comment: str[0,1] doesn't work the same in 1.8 and 1.9 either, as in the former it returns the first *byte* while in the latter it returns the first *character*.

Comment: That's not really a difference in how the indexing works so much as in 1.9's support for multibyte languages. They're both meant to return the first character, but 1.8 has a more naive view of what a "character" is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def word(string, num)
    string = 'Smith'
    string[0..(num-1)]
end
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Rails` You can also use [`truncate`](https://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate)

```
> 'Smith'.truncate(1, omission: '')
#=> "S"
```

or for additional formatting:

```
> 'Smith'.truncate(4)
#=> "S..."

> 'Smith'.truncate(2, omission: '.')
#=> "S."
```

While this is definitely overkill for the original question, for a pure `ruby` solution, here is how `truncate` is implemented in `rails`

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/filters.rb, line 66
def truncate(truncate_at, options = {})
  return dup unless length > truncate_at

  omission = options[:omission] || "..."
  length_with_room_for_omission = truncate_at - omission.length
  stop =        if options[:separator]
      rindex(options[:separator], length_with_room_for_omission) || length_with_room_for_omission
    else
      length_with_room_for_omission
    end

  "#{self[0, stop]}#{omission}"
end
```

Comment: truncate is only available in Rails?

Comment: @MartinThurn yes, good catch. Updated with a ruby implementation of `truncate`

Answer (score 0):

Other way around would be using the [chars](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chars) for a string:

```rb
def abbrev_name
    first_name.chars.first.capitalize + '.' + ' ' + last_name
end
```

Answer (score -3):

Any of these methods will work:

```
name = 'Smith'
puts name.[0..0] # => S
puts name.[0] # => S
puts name.[0,1] # => S
puts name.[0].chr # => S
```

Comment: _None_ of these methods will work with that `.` after `name`. And the last one is non-sensical even if you remove the `.`, because it's using two different methods to do the same thing – `[0]` _and_ `chr()`.