# Split utf8 string regardless of ruby version

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8, formatting

```
str = "é-du-Marché"
```

I get the first char via

```
str.split(//).first
```

How I can get the rest of the string regardless of my ruby version ?

Comment: Does `str.first` really work with ruby 1.9.2? I tried it and get a `undefined method `first' for "\u00E9-du-March\u00E9":String (NoMethodError)`. More hints to get the first character see [Ruby: How to get the first character of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730854/ruby-how-to-get-the-first-character-of-a-string)

Comment: I tested in meantime with ruby 1.8.6. String#split does also not exist. Do you mean `str.split(//).first`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String does not have a method first. So you need in addition a split. When you do the split in unicode-mode (exactly utf-8) you have acces to the first (and other characters).

My solution:

```
puts RUBY_VERSION
str = "é-du-Marché"
p str.split(//u, 2)
```

Test with ruby 1.9.2:

```
1.9.2
["\u00E9", "-du-March\u00E9"]
```

Test with ruby 1.8.6:

```
1.8.6
["\303\251", "-du-March\303\251"]
```

With `first` and `last` you get your results:

- `str.split(//u, 2).first` is the first character
- `str.split(//u, 2).last` is the string after the first character.

Answer (score 1):

`str[1..-1]` should return you everything after the first digit normally.

**The first number is the starting index**, which is set to 1 to skip the first digit, **the second is the length**, which is set to -1, so ruby counts from the back

*Note*: that multibyte characters only work in Ruby 1.9. If you wish to mimic this behavior downwards, you'll have to loop over the bytes yourself and figure out what needs to be removed from the data, cause Ruby 1.8 does not support this.

UPDATE:

You could try this as well, but I can't guarantee that it will work for every multibyte char:

```
str = "é-du-Marché"
substring = str.mb_chars[1..-1]
```

the **mb_chars** is a proxy class that directs the call to the appropiate implementation when dealing with UTF-8, UTF-32 or UTF-16 encoding of characters (e.g. multibyte chars).
More detailed info can be found here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars.html
But I do not know if this exists in older rails versions

**UPDATE2:**

Ruby 1.8 treats any string just as a bunch of bytes, calling size() on it will return the amount of bytes that is used to store the data. To determine the characters regardless of the encoding try this:

```
char_array = str.scan(/./m)
substring = char_array[1..-1].join
```

This should do the trick normally. Try looking at http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/bytes_and_characters_in_ruby_18 who explains how to treat multibyte data in older ruby versions.

**EDIT3**:

Playing around with the scan & join operations brings me closer to your problem & solution. I honestly don't have the time at to get the full solution working but if you play with the scan(/./mu) options you convert it to utf-8, which is supported by all ruby versions.

Comment: str = "\303\251-du-March\303\251" ;

str[1..-1] = "\251-du-March\303\251" because it is multibyte

Comment: isn't that what you wanted? From your response I deduct that it removed the first character, regardless whether it was multibyte or not...

Comment: This is obvious... that's why I'm asking here for the best approach of doing this

Comment: added a better example, but I'm not sure if it will work. Also gave you a link with more examples on how to treat multibyte data