# Find the first character in an array string

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to find the first character of a string inside an array. I would like to do something like this:

```
string = ["A", "B", 1234, 54321]
string[3].chars.first # => "5"
```

Doing `"string".chars.first # => "s"` only works for a string input.

Comment: It looks like you might want `arr = ["A","B",1234,54321];  
 arr[3].to_s[0] => "5"`. `["A","B",1234,54321]` is an array, so `str` is not a good choice for a variable name. Indices begin at zero, so the last element of `arr` is at index `3`. You need to first convert `arr[3]` to a string, in case (as here) it is not a string. Hence `arr[3].to_s[0]`. If it were at index `1`. `arr[1].to_s[0] #=> "B".

Comment: Once you turn the array value to_s you can use any of the solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730854/ruby-how-to-get-the-first-character-of-a-string

Comment: @Tot, what's the expression? "My bad?", meaning "I was bad".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change all of the elements of the array to strings then do what you were originally doing.

```
string = ["A", "B", 1234, 54321]
string.map { |x| x.to_s }[3].chars.first
=> "5"
```

Comment: Or just `string.[3].to_s.chars.first`?

Comment: Better to just convert the element of interest to a string.

Comment: @Oleander : there is syntax issue in your comment. unwanted `.` after string : `string[3].to_s.chars.first` I can't edit your comment so just point you

Comment: Or: `string[x].to_s[0]` You can skip `String#chars` and `Array#first` because strings are really just arrays under the hood so you can treat them as such. Access whatever element of the parent array, ensure that you convert it to a string, and then call the first element with `[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you convert all elements to string when you are interested to get first character of 3rd element of string array.

```
> string[3].to_s[0]
#=> "5"
```

**OR**

```
> string[3].to_s.chars.first
#=> "5"
```

Comment: IMO this is the better answer.